# What Does This Ruby/RegEx Code Do?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm going through Beginning Ruby From Novice To Professional 2nd Edition and am currently on page 49 where we are learning about RegEx basics. Each RegEx snippet in the book has a code trailing it that hasn't been explained.

```
{ |x| puts x }
```

In context:

```
"This is a test".scan(/[a-m]/) { |x| puts x }
```

Could someone please clue me in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method such as `scan` is an iterator; in this case, each time the passed regex is matched, `scan` does something programmer-specified.  In Ruby, the "something" is expressed as a *block*, represented by `{ code }` or `do code end` (with different precedences), which is passed as a special parameter to the method.  A block may start with a list of parameters (and local variables), which is the `|x|` part; `scan` invokes the block with the string it matched, which is bound to `x` inside the block.  (This syntax comes from Smalltalk.)

So, in this case, `scan` will invoke its block parameter every time `/[a-m]/` matches, which means on every character in the string between `a` and `m`.

Comment: Thanks geekosaur, this clicked! Will still have to read it a few more times.

Answer (score 1):

It prints all letters in the string between `a` and `m`: http://ideone.com/lKaoI

`|x| puts x` is an annonymouse function, (or a "block", in ruby, as far as I can tell, or a lambda in other languages), that prints its argument.
More information on that can be found in:

- [Wikipedia - Ruby - Blocks and iterators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#Blocks_and_iterators)
- [Understanding Ruby Blocks, Procs and Lambdas](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

Comment: I think he's asking what `{ |x| puts x }` does. I don't know Ruby, but I can only assume that it prints out the regex.

Comment: @Switz - I was getting to it, it took me quite some time to figure out how it is called in Ruby, and find some relevant reference.

Comment: @Kobi You should edit your answer to say "it prints all letters between between a and m *in the given string* or something like that.  One way to read your current answer is that it prints `abcdefghijklm`.  Just sayin' :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your book's examples, it's included after each expression because it just means "**Print out every match.**"

It is a [code block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#Blocks_and_iterators), which runs for each match of the regular expression.

`{ }` creates the code block.

`|x|` creates the argument for the code block

`puts` prints out a string, and `x` is the string it prints.

The regular expression matches any single character in the character class `[a-m]`. Therefore, there are five different matches, and it prints out:

```
h
i
i
a
e
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is

```
h
i
i
a
e
```

Each character of the string "This is a test" is checked against the regular expression `[a-m]` which means "exactly one character in the range `a..m`, and is printed on its own line (via `puts`) if it *matches*.  The first character `T` does not match, the second one `h` does match, etc.  The last one that does is the `e` in "test".

Answer (score 0):

The `{ |x| puts x }` defines a new block that takes a single argument named `x`.  When the block is called, it passes its argument `x` to `puts`.

Another way to write the same thing would be:

```
"This is a test".scan(/[a-m]/) do |x|
  puts x
end
```

The block gets called by the `scan` function each time the regular expression matches something in the string, so each match will get printed.

There is more information about blocks here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html